# How to assign custom type pointers?

Tags: go, pointers, struct, custom-type

I have:

```
type MyType string

type Source struct {
  Value *string
}

type Target struct {
  Value *MyType
}
```

Those are generated types created by a code generator from a JSON schema.

How can I assign `Source.Value` to `Target.Value`?

Would this be correct:

```
var target Target
var source Source

target.Value = new(MyType)
*target.Value = MyType(*source.Value)
```

Or is there a better way of doing it?

Comment: You can drop the `target.Value = new(MyType)` step, and just do `target.Value = (*MyType)(source.Value)`.

Comment: Even better, thanks! I was trying with casting to pointer type but missed the braces so I wouldn't succeed. Thanks for the hint.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Would this be correct [?]

Yes.

(But maybe I miss the point of your question as trying this out would have taken an order of magnitude less time than asking this here on SO.)

Comment: Well, actually while writing the question I was still trying around and came to the above solution. But still there could be better ways or it might be non-optimal for some reason. But thanks anyway.